# Select TOP 3 de cada Mês

Tags: mysql, select-limit

Preciso retornar o top 3 de uma consulta de cada mês:

```sql
select distinct  mes, rubrica, count(*) qtd
from boletins
group by mes, rubrica
order by mes asc, qtd desc;
```

Esta consulta acima retorna cerca de 30 linhas para cada mês, porém preciso apenas das 3 primeiras conforme abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: adicione `limit 3` no fim da consulta

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma sugestão para testes utilizando a função Row_Number para numerar as linhas por mês e em ordem decrescente de quantidade:

```
with CTE_RN as
(
    select 
        mes, 
        rubrica, 
        count(*) qtd,
        row_number() over(partition by mes order by count(*) desc) as RN
    from boletins 
    group by 
        mes, 
        rubrica 
)

select mes, rubrica, qtd
from CTE_RN
where RN <= 3
order by mes asc, qtd desc
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Estou usando o MySQL Workbench, e parece nao suportar as funções WITH e ROW_NUMBER

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CTE_RN as (     select          mes,          rubrica,          count(*) qtd,   ' at line 1 0,156 sec
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by mes order by count(*) desc) as RN     from boletins      group by ' at line 5 0,156

Comment: essa consulta parece mais com PL/SQL

Comment: Fabiana, qual versão do MySQL você está utilizando? O uso de CTE e da função Row_Number estão disponíveis a partir da versão 8.0